# How to get datetime column data from kafka

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Hello everybody I have problem and don't know how to fix it.
There is kafka source which delivers JSON with following format.

> {"CustomerId":606811,"Latitude":35.834896,"Longitude":50.019657,"Response":{"Stores":[{"Id":771,"LegacyStoreId":5497,"LegacyStoreTypeId":1,"PartnerId":3,"StoreName":"test","StoreDisplayName":"test","PartnerName":"test","ServiceRadius":3,"Longitude":56.009797,"Latitude":35.829067,"StatusCode":1,"CityId":200,"CityName":null,"Description":"test","IsOk24":false,"RouteDistanceInMeter":0,"IsRouteDistanceValid":false,"IsOutOfOrders":false,"AirDistanceInMeter":1100,"IsAirDistanceInValid":true,"IsDeliveryCoverage":true,"IsNonCoverageArea":false,"Rate":3.9,"Reviews":560,"IsHighPriorityStore":false,"StoreScore":0,"PartnerRank":1,"DeliveryCost":"80000","FirstDeliveryTime":"test","Labels":[],"MinCartTotalPrice":500000},{"Id":463,"LegacyStoreId":4765,"LegacyStoreTypeId":1,"PartnerId":3,"StoreName":"test","StoreDisplayName":"test","PartnerName":"test","ServiceRadius":3,"Longitude":56.995281,"Latitude":35.82251,"StatusCode":1,"CityId":200,"CityName":null,"Description":"test","IsOk24":false,"RouteDistanceInMeter":0,"IsRouteDistanceValid":false,"IsOutOfOrders":false,"AirDistanceInMeter":2593,"IsAirDistanceInValid":true,"IsDeliveryCoverage":true,"IsNonCoverageArea":false,"Rate":3.8,"Reviews":532,"IsHighPriorityStore":false,"StoreScore":0,"PartnerRank":1,"DeliveryCost":"80000","FirstDeliveryTime":"test","Labels":[],"MinCartTotalPrice":500000}]},"Id":"f2655da4-c236-4f86-9ca0-8063a4c77da8","CreationAt":"2023-06-18T14:49:11.8545562+03:30"}

I'm supposed to get data from it. Every thing is functioning very well exept CreationAt column. I dont know why my code is returning null for CreationAt Col.

```
spark= SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("striming") \
.config("spark.jars.packages","*****************") \
.config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', '/usr/local/spark/resources/jars/sqljdbc42.jar') \
.config('spark.executor.extraClassPath', '/usr/local/spark/resources/jars/sqljdbc42.jar') \
.config("spark.cores.max", "1") \
.config("spark.executor.memory", "1g") \
.config("spark.executor.cores", "1") \
.config("spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors", "1") \
.master("local[1]") \
.getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
kafka_df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","My Kafka Servers").option("subscribe","Event").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").option("failOnDataLoss","false").option('multiline', "True").load()

schema = StructType([StructField("CreationAt", TimestampType(), True),StructField("CustomerId", LongType(), True),
StructField("Id", StringType(), True),StructField("Latitude", DoubleType(), True),
StructField("Longitude", DoubleType(), True),StructField("Response",
    StructType([StructField("Stores",ArrayType(StructType([StructField("Id", IntegerType(), True),
StructField("LegacyStoreId", IntegerType(), True), StructField("LegacyStoreTypeId", IntegerType(), True),
StructField("PartnerId", IntegerType(), True),StructField("StoreName", StringType(), True),
StructField("StoreDisplayName", StringType(), True),StructField("PartnerName", StringType(), True)
])), True), ]), True),])

value_df = kafka_df.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("StoreSelection"))

value_df.printSchema()

sites_flat = value_df.selectExpr("StoreSelection")\.select("StoreSelection.CustomerId", "StoreSelection.Latitude", 
"StoreSelection.Longitude", "StoreSelection.CreationAt", explode_outer("StoreSelection.Response.Stores").alias("Stores"))\
.select( "CustomerId","Latitude","Longitude","CreationAt","Stores.LegacyStoreId", "Stores.StoreName", "Stores.PartnerName")\
.select( "CustomerId","Latitude","Longitude", "CreationAt","LegacyStoreId", "StoreName", "PartnerName")

sites_flat.printSchema()

def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
df.write \
df.show()


invoiceWriterQuery =
sites_flat.writeStream.foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).outputMode("update") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "/usr/local/airflow/dags/otime/log_file").trigger(
processingTime="1 minute").start().awaitTermination()
invoiceWriterQuery.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: You don't really need a schema. You can use `from_json_object`... The schema being incorrect is why data is null

Comment: You can read `CreationAt` column data as string then do transformation using `.withColumn` function